# How to listen only for push and pop events (and nothing else) in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I need some custom animation/transition logic that I want to drive when React Navigation native stack navigator pushes or pops a screen, however, I'm stuck as I can't reliable detect *only* push and pop events (and *not* tab change/modal events).

When I listen `beforeRemove` I can't reliably detect push. When I listen for `blur` it also triggers on tab change. When I try to use `focus` just like blur it also triggers on tab change. If I use `useFocusEffect` it acts like `blur` and `focus` anyway.

My navigation hierarch consists of multiple tabs, each having a root element of native stack navigator, and the screens inside those.

How can I detect `push` and `pop` and *ONLY* push and pop events in React Navigation?

I'm on React Native 0.72.4 and here is my React Navigation versions from package.json:

```
 "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
 "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
 "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.13",
```

Comment: Take a look here, it may helps. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#pop

Comment: @RodrigoDias I've (obviously) already read the docs, and the link you provided points to stack navigator, not _native_ stack navigator which are potentially different anyway.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to help, in any moment I said you didn´t read the docs.  I hope someone can help you to find the solution.

Comment: @RodrigoDias sure. I wasn't offensive. textual communication sometimes sounds harsh. no hard feelings. regarding the actual link content: perhaps `transitionStart` might do something though I don't see it passing all the needed data reliably (e.g. from which screen to which) from what I've examined.

Comment: No problem man, sure. No hard feelings. I've never used this transitionStart.